# Install guzzel/guzzel laravel 5 project

Tags: php, laravel-5

I installed koraktor/steam-condenser (https://packagist.org/packages/koraktor/steam-condenser) in my laravel project, but koraktor/steam-condenser need guzzel/guzzel (https://packagist.org/packages/guzzle/guzzle). I am tried to install guzzle/guzzle and got an Problem.

> E:\Projekti\csgo_project_1>composer require guzzle/guzzle
>
> Using
>   version ^3.9@dev for guzzle/guzzle ./composer.json has been updated 
>   php artisan clear-compiled Loading composer repositories with package
>   information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.5
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.3
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.1
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.0
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.0-BETA2
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v2.7.0-BETA1
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/event-dispatcher 2.8.x-dev
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/event-dispatcher[2.7.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/event-dispatcher[3.0.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev].
>       - Can only install one of: symfony/event-dispatcher[2.7.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].
>       - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher ~2.7 -> satisfiable by s ymfony/event-dispatcher[2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev, v2.7.0,
>   v2.7.0-BETA1, v2.7.0-BETA2 , v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5].
>       - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher == 3.0.9999999.9999999-d ev -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[3.0.x-dev].
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mention of here koraktor/steam-condenser needing guzzle/guzzle in https://packagist.org/packages/koraktor/steam-condenser

Anyway if koraktor/steam-condens have a dependency on guzzle/guzzle it should pull this dependency thought Composer. 
So you ONLY need to do:

```
composer require koraktor/steam-condenser
```

and it should automatically pull all of it's dependencies through the Composer.